# FancyBox inside a html form

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I have a normal html form. Inside the form I have several fields. Inside that form I ALSO have a lightbox div. Inside the light box i have a submit button. So it looks something like this:

```
<form action="path" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>

    <a href="#fancybox">Link to open fancybox</a>

    <div id="fancybox" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" name="captcha" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>

</form>
```

When I click on the link to open the fancy box and click the submit button. It doesn't work. The form isn't submitted.

Any ideas whats going on?
here is a jsfiddle of the situation [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZDZX/4/)

Comment: What happens? Nothing at all? Any errors?

Comment: nope nothing. its like a dead button.

Comment: If you inspect the fancybox overlay, you will find out that the submit button(on the overlay) is outside the form. You need to have form tag inside the fancybox div

Comment: oo ok ok ok. get it. Thanks!

Comment: as mentioned by @anpsmn, when you open inline content (as per your button) the taget content is "moved" into fancybox and a placeholder is left instead so that button will be outside the form. I would rather bind a `submit` action to the button inside fancybox

Comment: @JFK what do you mean bind a submit to the button inside fancybox? do u mean using js (if submit1.click then submit1.click) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is :

- add an ID or class to the `form` (a selector to play with)
- add an ID or class to the `submit` button

like :

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://jsfiddle.net" method="post">Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br/> <a href="#fancybox" class="fancybox">Link to open fancybox</a>

    <div id="fancybox" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="captcha" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="mySubmit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

then bind a `click` to the selector of the `submit` button and `submit` the `form` after fancybox is closed AND the input fields are back to their position in the `form` :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        $("#mySubmit").on("click", function () {
            $.fancybox.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#myForm").submit();
            }, 100); // wait for the inout field to be back inside the form then submit
        });
    }
});
```

**Notice** I am using `setTimeout()` to give some time for the fields to be replaced inside the `form` element. Also, if you want to validate the captcha inside fancybox, then include the proper scripts inside the same callback.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PTrN3/)**